# Нарисовать 3 графика функции

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
uses GraphABC;

const
  W = 900; H = 600; // в px
  N = 100;

function myRound(x:real):integer;
begin
  Result:=round(N*x);
end;  
var 
    array_y : array [1..3,0..10000] of single;
    array_t : array [0..10000] of single;
    t,    
    t_end,
    delta_t:single;
    i:integer;
begin

  t_end:= 10.0;
  delta_t:= 0.01;
  array_y[1,0]:= 1;
  array_y[2,0]:= 1;
  array_y[3,0]:= 1;

  array_t[0] := 0.0;
  t := 0.0;
  i:=1;
 SetWindowSize(W,H);
  while(t < t_end) do
    begin

      array_y[1,i] := 3 * array_t[i-1] + array_y[1,i-1] - array_y[1,i-1];
      array_y[2,i] := sin(array_t[i-1]) + array_y[2,i-1];
      array_y[3,i] := cos(array_t[i-1]) + array_y[1,i-1];


      t := t + delta_t;
      array_t[i] := array_t[i] + t;
  {Риcуем графики}
 setPixel(myRound(array_t[i]),myRound(array_y[1][i]),clRed); 
 setPixel(myRound(array_t[i]),myRound(array_y[2][i]),clGreen); 
 setPixel(myRound(array_t[i]),myRound(array_y[3][i]),clBrown); 

      i := i+1;
    end


end.
```

Нужно нарисовать 3 графика, но выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка времени выполнения: Параметр должен быть положительным и меньше 
>   ширины. Имя параметра: x

Как я понимаю проблема в том что выходим за границы экрана ?

Comment: `setPixel` - где? У Вас в вызовах `setPixel`, случайно, `array_y` с `array_t` не перепутаны?

Comment: В окне, размеры которого установил  используя `SetWindowSize`

Comment: да, массивы перепутал, но проблема осталась

Comment: где код функции `setPixel`?

Comment: это стандартный метод модуля  GraphABC

Answer (score 1):

Проблем как минимум три.

Первая проблема: в строке `array_y[3,i] := cos(array_t[i-1]) + array_y[1,i-1];`, второе слагаемое должно быть таким: `array_y[3,i-1]`.

Вторая проблема: `N = 100;`. Каждая единица N это увеличение высоты графиков, для второй и третьей функции, на 200 пикселей. Т. е. при `N = 100;` высота графиков составляет 20000 пикселей.

Третья проблема: В третьей функции, на вашем диапазоне значений она становится отрицательной. Соответственно чтобы её корректно отобразить ей надо при выводе добавлять половину её высоты. При `N = 1;` это 100 пикселей.